# Cannot submit facebook application!

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to submit an application on Facebook but it is outputting an error message "You need to have at least 10 monthly active users before you can submit your application", How can i get these 10 monthly active users. I am not being able even to test it

Answer (score 1):

You can invite testers, those ones do have access to the app so you can test your app. The testers do count to the active users.

Go to your app in the facebook developer thing, then info->manage users and add a user. After he accepted you change his status to "tester"

Comment: Also you don't need to submit for other to be able to use your app. Just disable the sandbox mode in the advanced settings of your app. By submitting you publish your app into the App index wich can be browsed by other facebook members. But you don't need to be in the index to be found by others, after disabling sandbox mode you could advertize your app on your ownn

Answer (score 0):

Use some business technique

- Spread the news to your friends
- Use online adveritzing.

The statistics can be seen on your app page.

Comment: But I have the app on facebook but i am not being able to even test it

Answer (score 0):

Create 10 fake Facebook accounts and invite them.